# Duplicate security elements when building custom soap request

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, soap, xml-serialization

I'm trying to send a soap request to a WCF service. I am building the soap request using the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage() method.

I haven't gotten super deep into building the body, but here is what I have...

```
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage( MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, "MethodName" );
msg.Headers.MessageId = new UniqueId( Guid.NewGuid().ToString() );
msg.Headers.Add( Message.CreateHeader( "Security", "",
    new Security()
    {
        TimeStamp = new TimeStampType() {
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Expires = Created.AddDays( 1 )
        },
        UsernameToken = new UsernameToken() {
            Username = "stackoverflow",
            Password = new Password() {
                Type = "hashed",
                Value = "Password"
            }
        }
     }, new SecuritySerializer() ) ) ); // The serializer inherits XmlObjectSerializer. Internally it is using the XmlSerializer class.

string s = msg.ToString();
```

When I run this, I get the following output. I'm using the Visual Studio XML Visualizer btw.

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
        <Action>MethodName</Action>
        <MessageID>GUIDVALUE</MessageID>
        <Security>
            <Security>
               .....
            </Security>
        </Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body />
</s:Envelope>
```

My question is, how can I remove one of the Security elements? I'm supposed to have one, but I have two since I first passed in the element name to the Message.CreateHeader() method and the second one was generated from the serializer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by making the Security class inherit from the MessageHeader abstract class. I then overrided the OnWriteHeaderContents method and serialized the properties there. Also I took out MessageHeader.CreateHeader() since the Security object is now a header object.

Comment: If you need a namespace prefix, you need to override the OnWriteStartHeader method and do something like
writer.WriteStartElement( "prefix", this.Name, this.Namespace )